# JQuery: OnClick adds new variable stack instead of overwriting values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Vimeo API and I want to get the duration data of the video when I click on a button. At the same time, when I click on the button, the player gets paused and after that, I want to overwrite `duration` and `currentDuration` variables.

Here are my related codes:

```
var duration = 0;
var currentDuration = 0;

async function asyncGetDuration() {
  return player.getDuration().then(function(duration) {
    return duration;
  })
}

function getDuration() {
  return asyncGetDuration();
}

(async() => {

  duration = await getDuration();
  currentDuration = await getCurrentDuration(); // I added this function with the same way of the getDuration()

  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    player.pause().then(
      player.on('pause', function() {
        console.log(duration);
        console.log(currentDuration);
      })
    );
  });

})();
```

When I try to click on the button, `console.log` shows variable stack. For example, when I click on the button three times, `console.log` shows me at the first time:

> videoDuration: 376
> currentDuration: 0

At the second time:

> videoDuration: 375.976
> currentDuration: 1.237
> videoDuration: 375.976
> currentDuration: 1.237

At the third time:

> videoDuration: 375.976
> currentDuration: 1.885
> videoDuration: 375.976
> currentDuration: 1.885
> videoDuration: 375.976
> currentDuration: 1.885

I'm trying to understand the logic of the async functions. Is this problem related to async functions or other else? How can I fix this?

Comment: Every time you run that function, you're reassigning the click event handler... Take your click handler out of your async IIFE and it should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `player.on('pause', ...)` you're adding another event listener. So if you click 4 times, you have 4 listeners for the `pause` event, and they each log a message.

There's no need for that event listener, just do it in the click listener.

You need to call the functions that get the duration in the event listener, not just when the page opens.

```
(async() => {

  $('#button').on('click', async function() {
    player.pause();
    let duration = await getDuration();
    let currentDuration = await getCurrentDuration(); // I added this function with the same way of the getDuration()
    console.log(duration);
    console.log(currentDuration);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I use this way, I cannot get the correct data of the video. Every time when I click on the button, it returns: videoDuration: 376
currentDuration: 0

Comment: I explained that in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: The question asked how to prevent the stacking, not how to get the correct durations. So I just answered that part.

Comment: I think I stated in the title of the question that I want to overwrite the variable value.